# JavaScript nao verifica campos em branco

Tags: javascript

Boa Noite, estou com um problema em meu codigo JS, peco para ele verificar se os campos estao vazios, mas quando executo a funcao com o campo vazio ele nao faz a tratativa, simplesmente ignora os if`s, ja procurei na internet como validar, mas o que acho sao exemplos muito parecidos com o que fiz

Segue o codigo em Js e abaixo o HTML

```
function calculaBask(){

var numA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value),
    numB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value),
    numC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c').value),
    delta = null,
    x1 = null, x2 = null;

/* TRATATIVAS */

//ver se nao esta vindo numeros nulos
if(numA == '' || numA == null){

    alert("Digite um numero valido para continuar.");
    return false;
}

if(numB == '' || numB == null){

    alert("Digite um numero valido para continuar.");
    return false;
}

if(numC == '' || numC == null){

    alert("Digite um numero valido para continuar.");
    return false;
}

//recebendo o valor de delta
delta = numB * numB - 4 * numA * numC;

//pegando a raiz de delta
raizDelta = Math.sqrt(delta);

//Calculando primeira raiz
x1 = (-numB + raizDelta) / 2 * numA ;

//calculando segunda raiz
x2 = (-numB - raizDelta) / 2 * numA;

document.getElementById('raiz1').value = x1;
document.getElementById('raiz2').value = x2;
document.getElementById('bd').value = delta;

}
```

```html
<header class="container">

        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Calcule Baskhara</h1>

    </header>

    <section class="container box-space secao-input">

        <label>Digite A:
            <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="">
        </label>

        <label>Digite B:
            <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="">
        </label>

        <label>Digite C: 
            <input id="c" type="text" placeholder="">
        </label>

    </section>

    <div class="container box-space results">
        <label class="label-rs">Raiz 1:
            <input id="raiz1" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="label-rs">Raiz 2:
            <input id="raiz2" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="label-rs">Binomio discriminante:
            <input id="bd" type="text">
        </label>
        <button onclick="calculaBask()" id="botao">Calcular</button>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você usa `parseFloat()` e o campo está vazio (que a princípio é o que você está tentando verificar), ele retorna a string `NaN` (*[not a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)* -- em português, *não é um número*). Com isso seu `if` valida as variáveis pois elas não estão mais vazias.

Se o campo estiver vazio ou não for um número, o código abaixo irá retornar `NaN`:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value);
```

**Solução:** Troque todas as condições nos `if`s por `isNaN()`:

```
if(!(numA) == '' || numA == null){
```

para

```
if(isNaN(numA)){
```

E assim por diante. [Clique aqui se quiser saber mais sobre o **`isNaN()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara, funcionou!!!!

Comment: @JoãoVizu Show! Importante para nós marcar ✓ na resposta. Abs!